# streamlit running old executions in background

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm currently working on a Python project using Streamlit. I've encountered an issue where every time I click on a menu button, Streamlit seems to reload, but instead of using the most recent code, it appears to revert and execute some older version of the code.

This behavior is problematic as it prevents me from seeing the expected results from the latest code changes. It feels as if the older code executions are being cached or persisting in some way.

Steps to reproduce:

Update the Streamlit code.
Run the Streamlit app.
Interact with the app, specifically by clicking on menu buttons.
Observe that the app reloads, but the execution seems to be based on a previous version of the code.
Has anyone else experienced this behavior with Streamlit? If so, are there any known solutions or workarounds to prevent this from happening? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible code?